# Visual Studio "Target framework" missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, ide, .net-4.5

I am trying to compile my .NET Standard class library project with .NET Framework 4.5.2. However, as you can see in my screenshot, version 4.5.2 is not shown in the offered list of target frameworks:

[image]

Furthermore, when I click **Install other frameworks...**, I am still not given the option of choosing 4.5.2.

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: Try to install/reinstall .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: I tried, it says that it is already installed.  Someway I can add it? @LabLab

Comment: Just to be clear there is no .net standard 4.5.2. There is a .Net Framework 4.5.2 (which will implement some level of the .net standard) see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7035edc6-97fc-49ee-8eee-2fa4d040a63b/what-are-differences-between-net-framwork-net-standard-and-net-core?forum=clr and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: you created a .net standard library with new csproj format. unload the project and edit the csproj and change the value in TargetFramework to net452

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You created the wrong project type. You created a `.Net Standard Class Library`

[image]

but you need to create a normal `Class Library` under `Windows Desktop` in the new project template

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no easy way to switch. I tried editing the project xml but Visual Studio kept throwing errors so ended up having to recreate the project. This would be painful for a large project.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy classic .net framework can be also used with new SDK style projects. I also do this. Don't know why it fails for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error like you
then I Copy that from my friend.
and pass
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework

[image]
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31875187)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Find this in your apps and features menu and try to uninstall. Then install it back and take a look what you got.