# Can't see framework 4.6.2 as option on my class library project

Tags: visual-studio, frameworks, visual-studio-2017

My friend gave me some sulotion that compiled under 4.6.2, it runs fine no errors,  I added to this solution a class library. when I click the properties of the my lib project I see only frameworks `1.0-1.6`

[image]

Even that I already have 4.6.2 framework installed on my machine, I'm using visual stutio 2017.

please share knowlagh

Comment: I found the issue, When I opened a new class library project it was "Standard", needed to choose "Class Library(.NET Framework)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio Target framework missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986565/visual-studio-target-framework-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class library project's target framework is .Net Standard that's why you only see .Net Standard project frameworks in project properties target framework list.

Benefit of building your library in .Net Standard is. Your project can be referenced in .Net and .Net Core Projects.

[image]

[image]